# Proper install dependency by requirements.txt or how to properly install dependency which was edited

Tags: python, git, heroku, dependencies, pip

I am using this dependency on my django site.

```
https://bitbucket.org/tim_heap/django-bleach
```

Problem is on django 1.9 there is a fix, and the repository was forked to someone else.

This is the repository

```
https://bitbucket.org/C14L/django-bleach.git
```

And this is the fix

```
https://bitbucket.org/C14L/django-bleach/commits/4dd2616f490d5d63bc119b24e07fdf8154f25503
```

On both there is manual how to install it

```
pip install django-bleach
```

But that is the same I would end up with the same error. I would like to install the fixed version. I can edit it manually on my localhost - it is not proper software engineering, so I would like to know proper way. But this is not the problem, problem is how to install it on heroku and I do not want to edit the dependency with CLI on heroku.

Can you help me what would be the proper way to install this fix on heroku and my localhost from that repository? What I need to put in the requirements.txt that it would install the correct fix?

```
https://bitbucket.org/C14L/django-bleach/commits/4dd2616f490d5d63bc119b24e07fdf8154f25503
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put repository urls in `requirements.txt` like so:

```
git+https://bitbucket.org/C14L/django-bleach.git
```

or be more specific and specify the branch:

```
git+https://bitbucket.org/C14L/django-bleach.git@django_1_9_fix
```

[Pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support).